# django-rest-framework accept JSON data?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have created RESTFul APIs using [django-rest-framework](/questions/tagged/django-rest-framework). The user endpoint is: `/api/v1/users`

I want to create a new user, so I send the user data in JSON format:

```
{
    "username": "Test1",
    "email": "test1@gmail.com",
    "first_name": "Test1",
    "last_name": "Test2",
    "password":"12121212"
}
```

I am using Google Chrome extension Postman to test the API. But, after sending the request, the user data is not saving. The response contains this error:

```
{
    "detail": "Unsupported media type \"text/plain;charset=UTF-8\" in request."
}
```

This is what the request details look like in Postman:

[image: Postman API request to django-rest-framework error]

Comment: By the way, postman version 2.0 is released, it has a wonderful UX and new features with newman automated rest api test :
http://blog.getpostman.com/index.php/2013/09/05/postman-packaged-app-release/

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You have missed adding the `Content-Type` header in the headers section. Just set the `Content-Type` header to `application/json` and it should work.

See the below image:

[image: postman]

Also, you might also need to include a CSRF token in the header in case you get an error `{"detail": "CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing or incorrect."}` while making a `POST` request using Postman. In that case, add an `X-CSRFToken` header also with value as the CSRF token value.

Answer (score 11):

I'm posting this answer in case someone is facing a problem like mine.

I'm working on a Front-End app using **Angular 2** with an API made with **Django Rest Framework** and I used to send requests with the following headers:

```
'Content-Type': 'application/json'
```

And it was working fine until I tried it on **Fire Fox** and I couldn't load the needed data and I solved it with adding the following headers

```
'Content-Type': 'application/json',
'Accept': 'application/json'
```

Here's an explanation, [`Content-Type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) tells the server what is the content type of data is while [`Accept`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept) tells it what content type the client side will accpet.

Here's a nice clear answer about this issue:

> https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/31212/difference-between-the-accept-and-content-type-http-headers

Answer (score 7):

You need to do two step to done this issue:

1. Add `Content-Type` header with `application/json` value
2. Add `Authorization` header with `Token {YOUR_CUSTOM_TOKEN}` value to pass CSRFToken

**Note**: if you want to authenticate with session, you don't need to do second step, but if you want use this API for mobile, you have to pass Authorization header to server

I hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

You need to define content type by setting the appropriate headers. In case of Postman you need to set the following values under url field:

Header: "Content-Type"

Value: application/json

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things to do if you want to accept JSON Data using Django Rest Framework.

1. Make sure application/json headers are sent:
   `'Content-Type: application/json'`
2. JSON Parser is selected in `settings.py`

```
    REST_FRAMEWORK = {
        'DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES': [
            'rest_framework.parsers.JSONParser',
        ],    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to add the following to get this to work (I'm using node-fetch btw from the client side to do a POST):

```
supportHeaderParams: true,
headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8" },
```