# Django Rest Framework, How to CREATE or UPDATE object that has a nested serializer as one of its fields

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, crud

I have two models `Product` and `Variant` as follows

models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    GENDER = [
        ('M', 'male'),
        ('F', 'female'),
        ('U', 'unisex'),
    ]
    store = models.ForeignKey(
        Store, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='products')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True, blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=GENDER)
    image_1 = models.URLField()
    image_2 = models.URLField()
    category = models.ForeignKey(
        'Category', related_name="products", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    return_policy = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    in_warehouse = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_rejected = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_disabled = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    score = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name



class Variant(models.Model):
    
COLORS = [
        ('black', 'Black'),
        ('grey', 'Grey'),
        ('white', 'White'),
        ('blue', 'Blue'),
        ('green', 'Green'),
        ('yellow', 'Yellow'),
        ('orange', 'Orange'),
        ('red', 'Red'),
        ('purple', 'Purple'),
        ('gold', 'Gold'),
        ('silver', 'Silver'),
        ('brown', 'Brown'),
        ('pink', 'Pink'),
        ('colorless', 'Colorless'),
        ('multi-colored', 'Multi Colored'),
    ]
    SIZES = [
        ('xxs', 'XXS'),
        ('xs', 'XS'),
        ('s', 'S'),
        ('m', 'M'),
        ('l', 'L'),
        ('xl', 'XL'),
        ('xxl', 'XXL'),
        ('xxxl', 'XXXL')
    ]
    product = models.ForeignKey(
        Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="variants", null=True, blank=True)
    is_default = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    price = models.FloatField()
    old_price = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    size = models.CharField(
        max_length=20, choices=SIZES, null=True, blank=True)
    shoe_size = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=COLORS)
    image = models.URLField()
    is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product.name + " variant"
```

I would like to CREATE a product while passing a list of `variants` so it can automatically create the variants with the product as follows

serializer.py

```
class VariantSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    image = serializers.ImageField()

    class Meta:
        model = Variant
        fields = ['product', 'is_default', 'price',
                  'old_price', 'quantity', 'size', 'shoe_size', 'color', 'image']


class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    variants = VariantSerializer(many=True)
    image_1 = serializers.ImageField()
    image_2 = serializers.ImageField()

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['store', 'name', 'description', 'brand',
                  'model', 'gender', 'image_1', 'image_2', 'category']

    def validate_category(self, value):
        if not Category.objects.filter(slug=value).exists():
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                {'category': 'category does not exist!'})

    def validate_variants(self, value):
        if len(value) > 5:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                "Maximum of 5 serializers per product")
        return value

    def validate_store(self, value):
        request = self.context.get('request')
        if not Store.objects.filter(id=value, user=request.user).exists():
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                {'store': 'Store does not exist!'})

    def create(self, validated_data):
        name = validated_data.get("name")
        store = validated_data.get("store")
        image_1 = validated_data.pop("image_1")
        image_2 = validated_data.pop("image_2")
        variants = validated_data.pop("variants")
        category = validated_data.pop("category")

        product = Product(**validated_data)
        product.save()
        # Handle category
        category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=category)
        product.category.set(category)
        # Handle Slug
        slug = slugify(name) + '-' + str(product.id)
        product.slug = slug
        # Handle Variant
        for variant in variants:
            variant["product"] = product.id
            new_variant = VariantSerializer(data=variant)
            if new_variant.is_valid():
                image = variant.pop("image")
                new_variant.image = None
                new_variant.save()
                try:
                    image_data = cloudinary.uploader.upload(image,
                                                            public_id=f'jetronmall/{settings.CLOUD_FOLDER_NAME}/stores/{store.id}/products/{product.id}/variants/{new_variant.id}',
                                                            crop='fill',
                                                            width='500',
                                                            height='500',
                                                            format='webp')
                    image = image_data.get("secure_url")
                    new_variant.image = image
                    new_variant.save()
                except:
                    product.delete()
                    raise serializers.ValidationError(
                        {"image": "cloudinary failed to upload"})
            else:
                product.delete()
                raise serializers.ValidationError(
                    {"variants": new_variant.errors})
        # Handle Image
        try:
            image_1_data = cloudinary.uploader.upload(image_1,
                                                      public_id=f'jetronmall/{settings.CLOUD_FOLDER_NAME}/stores/{store.id}/products/{product.id}/1',
                                                      crop='fill',
                                                      width='500',
                                                      height='500',
                                                      format='webp')
            image_1 = image_1_data.get("secure_url")
            product.image_1 = image_1
            image_2_data = cloudinary.uploader.upload(image_1,
                                                      public_id=f'jetronmall/{settings.CLOUD_FOLDER_NAME}/stores/{store.id}/products/{product.id}/2',
                                                      crop='fill',
                                                      width='500',
                                                      height='500',
                                                      format='webp')
            image_2 = image_2_data.get("secure_url")
            product.image_2 = image_2
            product.is_deleted = False
            product.save()
        except:
            product.delete()
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                {"images": "cloudinary failed to upload"})
        return product
```

The data I tried to POST was

```
{
    "name": "first product",
    "category": "tops",
    "brand": "first",
    "model": "test",
    "description": "someone is the ehd  kdvk kja avm elgm klrm gkrlng lkrgn rgn ognr bonr btklbn lbknb klnb rkngrkla rkgnrkgrng",
    "image_1": File,
    "image_2": File,
    "gender": "U",
    "variants": [
        {
            "price": "23000",
            "quantity": "4",
            "image": File,
            "size": "m",
            "shoe_size": "4",
            "color": "black",
            "is_default": true
        },
        {
            "price": "44",
            "quantity": "44",
            "image": File,
            "size": "m",
            "shoe_size": "44",
            "color": "black",
            "is_default": false
        },
        {
            "price": "22222",
            "quantity": "22",
            "image": File,
            "size": "m",
            "shoe_size": "22",
            "color": "black",
            "is_default": false
        }
    ]
}
```

But it throw me a `415 Unsupported Media Type`

```
{"detail":"Unsupported media type \"application/json;charset=UTF-8\" in request."}
```

so how am I meant to implement this logic using nested serializers?

Comment: Can you share the full traceback?

Comment: there is no trace back the error is just a `415` response error `Unsupported media type`

Comment: Ah I see. Are you using postman? If so based from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31121191/6759844) you have to set the content type to `application/json`

Comment: i'm not using postman, i'm using a form from a browser

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem i just had to add the header
`headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" },`